# Reading only a certain part of the Filename in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to this Page just now but already got a Question to ask.

Ok, I'm right now on a bigger Project (for me atleast) for a Server Interface of round about 3 Minecraft Servers on one machine.

Now I got to the point where I no longer want to call the startfiles manually, so i created a function that creates a Savefile with the location of the "servers" startfile (it's a simple batchfile) called "(name_of_server)_SAVEFILE(number_of_server).txt".

And now i want the Program to show me (best on startup) how many Servers actually have been saved by asking for the number talked about earlier.

I also want to implement a lock so the filenumber already created can't be saved with another name, but that's a different story there.

I did it like this:

```
    private void checkForServer_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\" + system_user + @"\Desktop\savedServers\*1.txt") == true)
        {
            string server1_location = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + system_user + @"\Desktop\savedServers\*_SAVEFILE1.txt");
            checkForServer_response.Text = "There are Servers!";
            onlyInfo.Clear();
            onlyInfo.Text = "[CONSOLE] Found existing Server! Found at: " + server1_location;
        }
    }
```

onlyInfo is a RichTextBox used as a dummy output atm, might stay in the final version to show what the saved batchfiles look like.

Yes, so basically my code does nothing when I click the button.

And another Question, how do I set the "*" properly for this type of usage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Exists` does not support wild characters in the file name. And neither does `File.ReadAllText`.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\" + system_user + 
  @"\Desktop\savedServers\", "*1.txt");
if (files.Length > 0)
{
  string server1_location = File.ReadAllText(files[0]);
  ...
}
```

Comment: To clarify @Igor's response, `File.Exists("wildcard expression")` is actually implemented by listing the files that match the wildcard expression and then checking if the list is empty.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you!